# List of files variable type reset after calling the async List type of API

Tags: flutter, dart

I am passing the List of Files to the function. That List of Files variable reset after calling the DB API. That API return type is List. And there is no way to reset `attachFiles` from another way.

**This is my function**

```dart
   List<File> attachFiles = [];

  Future postRequest(BuildContext context, PostModel postModel) async {
    List<RequirementModel> requirements = [];
    attachFiles = postModel.fileNotifierValues;
    print('attach files-1 : ${attachFiles?.length}');
    requirements = List.from(await db.checkRequirement(postModel.customerId, postModel.subCategory.subCategoryId));
    print('attach files-2 : ${attachFiles?.length}');
...
}
```

**Output result**

```
attach files-1 : 1
attach files-2 : 0
```

**checkRequirement function**

```dart
  Future<List<RequirementModel>> checkRequirement(String uid, String subId) async {
    var ref = _db
        .collection('requirement')
        .where('status', isEqualTo: 'Active')
        .where('customerId', isEqualTo: uid)
        .where('subCategory.id', isEqualTo: subId);

    List<RequirementModel> model = await ref.get().then((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => RequirementModel.fromForestore(doc)).toList());
    if ((model?.length ?? 0) != 0) {
      model.removeWhere((element) => element.enquiryPrivate == true);
      model.removeWhere((element) => element.isPromoInquiry == true);
      return model;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

**flutter doctor -v**

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale
> en-LK)
> • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/bhanukaisuru/dev/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision 18116933e7 (8 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
> • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
> • Dart version 2.14.4
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
> • Android SDK at /Users/bhanukaisuru/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
> Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 13.1, Build version 13A1030d
> • CocoaPods version 1.11.2
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
> • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
> • Flutter extension version 3.29.0
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
> • PRA LX2 (mobile) • 6MU7N17A12000618 • android-arm64  • Android 8.0.0 (API
> 26)
> • Chrome (web)     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome
> 96.0.4664.55
>
> • No issues found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Dart language issue. I change my code into this. Now it's working fine.

from

```
attachFiles = postModel.fileNotifierValue;
```

to this

```
attachFiles = List.from(postModel.fileNotifierValue ?? []);
```